# didSelectRowAtIndexPath for the entire cell does not work

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, clickable

I have made a custom UITableViewCell, this cell has icons, labels and text views within it. I want to make the entire cell clickable but i can't make it work.

I use the following code to handle the click

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This only works if you touch the cell where there are no textviews, how do i make the entire cell clickable?

Comment: Try to make your textViews non editable `textView.editable = NO;`

Comment: are you using storyboards or code to create the cell?

Comment: make all your icons, labels and text views not userinteraction enabled, or in the case of textview like Mattias Bauch has put it, not editable. :)